# Структура PE-файла

Tags: windows, pe

Почему в PE файле отсутствует таблица релоков? Как такое может быть и как системный загрузчик обрабатывает такую ситуацию (при загрузке не по ImageBase)?

[image: Вывод программы PeTools]